# Transform array to complicated object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to convert that array of items to object like below

```
const items = [
        {
          "title": "Nauczyc sie ngrx",
          "description": "Naucycz sie ngrxrx",
          "type": "[Todos] Add Todo",
          "id": 2
        },
        {
          "title": "Nauka NgRx i jakieś inne",
          "description": "Jakieś tam takie",
          "type": "[Todos] Add Todo",
          "id": 3
        },
        {
          "title": "Jakieś tam takie tam",
          "description": "Takie tam takie tam takie",
          "type": "[Todos] Add Todo",
          "id": 4
        },
        {
          "title": "Nowa - Nowa - Nowa",
          "description": "Nowe zadanie nowe zadanie",
          "type": "[Todos] Add Todo",
          "id": 5
        }
      ]
```

To object like that but with all the options in my items for example.

```
{
    id: {
      label: 'Id',
      options: [
        { label: 1, value: 1 },
        { label: 2, value: 2 },
      ],
    },
    title: {
      label: 'Title',
      options: [
        { label: 'Nauczyc sie ngrx', value: 'Nauczyc sie ngrx'}
      ],
    }
  }
```

But with all options to title, ids, description and type. I'm stuck at this code and now trying to assign array to options with objects but don't know how, can somebody help and explain how it can be solved?:

```js
const items = [{
    "title": "Nauczyc sie ngrx",
    "description": "Naucycz sie ngrxrx",
    "type": "[Todos] Add Todo",
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "title": "Nauka NgRx i jakieś inne",
    "description": "Jakieś tam takie",
    "type": "[Todos] Add Todo",
    "id": 3
  },
  {
    "title": "Jakieś tam takie tam",
    "description": "Takie tam takie tam takie",
    "type": "[Todos] Add Todo",
    "id": 4
  },
  {
    "title": "Nowa - Nowa - Nowa",
    "description": "Nowe zadanie nowe zadanie",
    "type": "[Todos] Add Todo",
    "id": 5
  }
]
data = {};
items.forEach(i => {
  for (let key in i) {
    console.log('i', i)
    data[key] = {
      label: key,
    };
  }
})
console.log('result', data);
```

Comment: Hi, Can you clarify to me your question? What is the input and what is the output?

Comment: Please explain, in plain words, how you want the data moved. There seems to be no obvious correlation between the first set of data and the second.

Answer (score 0):

The way I will go about it is to

- have a function return the bare bone object
- Loop through each object and it keys and construct the output.

I used reduce in the code below, but you can also use forEach depending on your preference.

```js
const items = [
        {
          "title": "Nauczyc sie ngrx",
          "description": "Naucycz sie ngrxrx",
          "type": "[Todos] Add Todo",
          "id": 2
        },
        {
          "title": "Nauka NgRx i jakieś inne",
          "description": "Jakieś tam takie",
          "type": "[Todos] Add Todo",
          "id": 3
        },
        {
          "title": "Jakieś tam takie tam",
          "description": "Takie tam takie tam takie",
          "type": "[Todos] Add Todo",
          "id": 4
        },
        {
          "title": "Nowa - Nowa - Nowa",
          "description": "Nowe zadanie nowe zadanie",
          "type": "[Todos] Add Todo",
          "id": 5
        }
      ]

const keySkeletonObject = (key) => (
  {
    label: key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1),
    options: []
  }
);

const result = items.reduce((acc, val) => {
  Object.keys(val).forEach(key => {
    if(!acc[key]) acc[key] = keySkeletonObject(key);
    
    acc[key].options.push({label: val[key], value: val[key]})
  })
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```